# C# SSL3.0 Experian NetConnect responding with complition code 1000 - which is "Invalid Request Type"

Tags: c#, xml

I'm currently testing connection to `Experian` server to make sure that our development environment can communicate with `Experian` by sending information via `.xml` file and getting response back.

`Experian` will no longer support `SSL 3.0` and will remove `SSL 3.0` from its valid `encryption` method when connecting to its Demo environment, so I need to make sure that our system will be able to pull 1 test file.

I'm able to send the request and also `Experian` response back, but instead of responding with a valid `xml` file, it send `xml` with error message saying that request has invalid format.

This is what I submit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<NetConnectRequest xmlns="http://www.experian.com/NetConnect" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.experian.com/NetConnect NetConnect.xsd">

<EAI>some code</EAI>
<DBHost>STAR</DBHost>
<ReferenceId>1</ReferenceId>
<Request xmlns="http://www.experian.com/WebDelivery" version="1.0">
   <Products>
     <CreditProfile>
       <Subscriber>
         <Preamble></Preamble>
         <OpInitials></OpInitials>
         <SubCode></SubCode>
       </Subscriber>
       <PrimaryApplicant>
         <Name>
           <Surname></Surname>
           <First></First>
         </Name>
         <SSN></SSN>
         <CurrentAddress>
           <Street></Street>
           <City></City>
           <State></State>
           <Zip></Zip>
          </CurrentAddress>
          <DOB></DOB>
        </PrimaryApplicant>
        <AddOns>
          <FraudShield></FraudShield>    
          <RiskModels>
            <FICO3></FICO3>
            <Bankruptcy></Bankruptcy>
          </RiskModels>
        </AddOns>
        <OutputType>
          <XML>
            <Verbose></Verbose>
          </XML>
        </OutputType>
        <Vendor>
          <VendorNumber></VendorNumber>
        </Vendor>
      </CreditProfile>
    </Products>
  </Request>
</NetConnectRequest>
```

Has anyone ever submitted any request to `Experian` after they stopped supporting `SSL 3.0` and what is the solution? I'm assuming that my `XML` has some invalid fields

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing, Experian plans to support SSL v3 for NetConnect until March 7, 2015, so it hasn't been disabled yet.

As long as your HTTP client is configured to use TLS 1.0 or higher, you shouldn't have any new problems pulling files.  If you are trying to write a test case, make sure your POST request has a `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and that the request body takes the form

```
NETCONNECT_TRANSACTION=<the-xml-request/>
```